# Is it possible to prevent the Bootstrap carousel pause on mouse hover and continue automatically cycling?

Tags: javascript, hover, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to prevent the Bootstrap carousel pause on mouse hover behaviour and continue automatically cycling through the items instead?

The documentation only mentions the default behaviour of `pause: "hover"`, if I change the pause argument to anything else then the carousel stops working altogether so I'm not sure how to disable this default behaviour.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've found that a value of `"false"` will cause the carousel to keep cycling during a mouseover:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: "false"
});
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v2.0.2

Comment: User `"pause":"false"` for IE compability!

Comment: Works with Bootstrap v3.1.1 too!

Answer (score 65):

You can add this to the div .carousel too instead of using javascript.

Add delay time:

`data-interval="3000"`

Add if it pauses on hover or not, options are `true` and `false`

`data-pause="false"`

Example would be:

`<div id="carousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="false">`

This worked for me.

Comment: This is a great working solution, I have tried this with Bootstrap 4 on Safari and Chrome. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This is a great working solution, I have tried this with Bootstrap 4 on Safari and Chrome. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: In newer bootstrap versions, you may have to use "data-bs-..."

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: 'none'
    })
```

for Bootstrap v3.3.4

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Comment: For Bootstrap 3.3.7 the value should be `null`:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options

Answer (score 6):

for Bootstrap v5.1

```
data-bs-pause="false"
```

Eg: `<div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel"  data-bs-pause="false">`

Comment: the additional "-bs-" was, what did it for me – apparently that changed in some bootstrap version, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 Remove Pause on hover

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "null"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still visiting this thread, in the most recent version of 4.1.3, use **null** without quotations. Maybe quotes were required in previous v.4 versions, but not the case now:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000,
    cycle: true,
    pause: null
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 :

> data-pause="false"

Eg: `<div class="carousel slide" id="carousel" data-pause="false" data-ride="carousel">`

This setting prevents the pause.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there are 2 things on which this cycling and pausing depends.

1. When mouse enters (**mouseenter - pause sliding**)
2. When mouse leaves (**mouseleave - resume sliding**)

Just change following line of code in your js/bootstrap.js file to allow continuous sliding.

`.on('mouseenter', $.proxy(this.pause, this))`  to

`.on('mouseenter', $.proxy(this.**cycle**, this))`

Comment: Editing source files is a terrible idea. All your changes will be lost if you choose to upgrade. Also a lot of developers choose to use external hosted files (e.g. those hosted on bootstrapcdn.com) and can't even be changed.

Moreover, when you change a source file for your entire website, you might get unexpected results on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize data attributes and append the option name to `data-bs-`. For this case, it should be `data-bs-pause="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Carousel pause="false" interval={5000}>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide" />
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

Here is for React

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).